# Is there a better way of obtaining a rgb matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a python program that takes some image and converts it to an ASCII art. 
The project is taken from [Robert Heaton](https://robertheaton.com/2018/12/08/programming-projects-for-advanced-beginners/) web page where he proposes some programming projects to develop your skills.

Well, at one point, I have to obtain the rgb values from each pixel and store them in a matrix and I think this can be done in a better way than I did it. Here is my code:

```
def extractPixels(img=None):
    '''
    This function will receive a Image object and return
    a 2D matrix containing pixels information
    '''
    if(type(img) == None or not(Image.isImageType(img))):
        raise TypeArgumentError("You have to pass a Image object")

    dataMatrix = []
    auxList = []
    for i in range(0, img.width, 1):
        for j in range(0, img.height, 1):
            auxList.append(img.getpixel((i,j)))
        dataMatrix.append(auxList)
        auxList = []

    return dataMatrix
```

I'm using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library for image processing.

This code

```
img.getpixel(i,j)
```

will return the tuple (R,G,B) for each pixel.

Comment: `list(Image.open("myimage.ext").getdata())` pure PIL method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do any explicit loop... you can just convert the image to a `numpy` array directly

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image
img = numpy.uint8(Image.open("myimage.jpg"))
h, w, _ = img.shape
```

then

```
r, g, b = img[y][x]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm pretty new with python and i didn't know about numpy.uint8 method